# MKMapView moveRight/Left on keyDown:

Tags: macos, cocoa, mapkit, mkmapview

I have mkmapview with move up, move down, zoom which works out of the box on key press. However move left/move right doesn't.

It works in default Maps.app and Maps doesn't use any subclassing.

Tried it with map that display compass without success.

I have subclassed MKMapView and I am not getting right/left keypress

```
- (void)keyDown:(NSEvent *)event
{
    [super keyDown:event];
}
```

What do I miss?

Tested on macOS 10.12.

[image: MKMapView]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the subclass of MKMapView you need to overwrite acceptsFirstResponder

```
   override var acceptsFirstResponder: Bool {
        return true
    }
```

Then all will work. I just made a test.